# what is the name of the very bottom of the eclipse window? I want to turn it off but can't until I know what its called

Tags: eclipse

I like to keep as much of my Eclipse screen as possible for code.  So I try to disable or turn off as many of the extra bars and such as possible.  The area at the very bottom of the Eclipse screen is my next target but I don't know what it's called.

Can anyone tell me the name of this area and how to reclaim it?  Thanks.

[image: Eclipse bottom]

Comment: Interesting! All those answers don't really fix this problem in a right way. There is no solution (through options, preferences, etc.) as of now! Eclipse fails to do basic UI customization!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an eclipse plug-in](http://ugosan.org/lot-of-space-with-eclipse-fullscreen/) which hides/shows Menu bar and/or Status bar.

User can change these options in `Windows > Preferences > Full Screen`

But Hiding Status bar was NOT working on my machine

`Ubuntu 13.10 Eclipse Version: Kepler Release Build id: 20130614-0229`

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm.

A few folks said my screen looked small...I was just trying to make it easier to see for my question.  I'm actually running NoMachine into an AWS Ubuntu instance.

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse oxygen there is option to hide status bar:

**Windows->Appearance->Hide_status_bar**

Answer (score 1):

I can see why you're eager to close that. It looks like your screen resolution is extremely low. Are you using a netbook perhaps?

Here's the problem though: On your screen, that part looks quite large and looks empty but it's because of your screen size. I'm fairly certain it doesn't have a name and having scoured the options, I'm convinced it can't be removed. On my screen, that section contains only a few words: "Writable | Smart Insert | 423:32"

Essentially, the words that show up there are a guide for your current editing mode and location in the file. I don't think it can be turned off. If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, it will hide almost everything possible on maximize your editor view.

On my screen, that little bar is very small. That is of course because I have a high screen resolution. If possible, try increasing the resolution on your screen to something more appropriate. You'll find you have a lot more space to code, and that little bar will become much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

This are is called the Status Line but it composed of a number of different components such as the progress indicator, editor current line and row, and the message area.

I am not aware of anything that will turn it all off.