# How to remove unnecessary space on bottom eclipse panel/toolbar?

Tags: eclipse

I'd like to remove some of the draggable toolbars/notifications (I don't know the proper name) on Eclipse to save valuable pixel space.

My eclipse looks like this:

[image: eclipse screenshot]

1. There is a draggable element on the bottom right that just seems to be taking up space. I tried dragging it off the screen and to other places to no avail. What is it, and how can I remove it?
2. The notifications about line number etc are also not very helpful to me. How can I remove these?

The reason why I ask is that they truncate the compiler error messages which I find very helpful to be able to quickly glance at. I'm very good at generating lots of error messages.

Comment: The 'empty' space is the progress area which displays the progress of various long running tasks

Answer (score 0):

By hiding status bar you can hide the line number information and `Empty draggable area`.

Please this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/22499193/1391924 and this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/23366443/1391924